# Nexus 5 not using h592dp dimen value. Why?

Tags: android, android-resources

I measure that Nexus 5 is using 592dp height. Even though it has 640dp, part of them are used as by the soft button.

So I have a layout, which resource dimen value I defined in all 3 dimens.xml below with different values.

```
res/values/dimens.xml 
res/values-h592dp/dimens.xml 
res/values-h640dp/dimens.xml
```

I'm expecting it to pick up the one from `values-h592dp`. However it is picking up from the default `value` folder instead. Why is this so? Did I miss anything?

Comment: i am also facing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No solution found so far yet.

Comment: Hey you can also try using "values-w360dp-h610dp" for 640dp devices and "values-w360dp" for 592dp devices, seems to be working for me. As mentioned in the link https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
Read the note : **The sizes that you specify using these qualifiers are not the actual screen sizes. Rather, the sizes are for the width or height in dp units that are available to your activity's window. **

Comment: Thanks Pranav. Apparently we can't set the exact value, but need some value that is lower than the height. I don't know why, but I'm posting an answer below based on my finding. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried with using lower value and it worked. And i also don't know the exact reason.

Comment: Pranav, found the logical reason behind this. Put an answer below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently not like width, we can't set the exact Height as per the device cauculated (e.g. 592dp for Nexus 5 or 640dp for Samsung 7). The height that it need to set is the one the calculated height - the status bar height.

```
use h509dp for Samsung SII that has height 533.33dp - 24dp (status bar)
use h567dp for Nexus 5 that has 592dp height - 25dp (status bar) 
use h616dp for Samsung S7 that has 640dp height - 24dp (status bar)
use h615dp for Samsung Note II that has 640dp height - 25dp (status bar)
```

For Samsung S7 and Note II, they could share h615dp. Refer to https://medium.com/@elye.project/an-important-note-when-managing-different-screen-height-3140e26e381a#.tljbmvc2x for more illustration of this.